# How to do non-blocking on RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ. I just started yesterday. I did few spikes on sending and consuming stuff. What I noticed was on their documentation and even on articles that I've read most of them are implementing the subscription piece in a way that they are looping it to get the message from a queue. How can I make it so that it will be event driven? What I wanted to accomplish is when a message is sent to a queue it will raise and event to the receiver and do something about it. Perhaps like displaying the message.

Your reply is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the examples use that looping style because it's easier to explain and understand.

You want to use [IModel.BasicConsume](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v2.8.1/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-2.8.1-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.html#method-M%3aRabbitMQ.Client.IModel.BasicConsume%28System.String,System.Boolean,RabbitMQ.Client.IBasicConsumer%29) instead of `BasicGet`.  See the [API Guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v2.8.1/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-2.8.1-user-guide.pdf) for examples (search for subscribe and consume).

Answer (score 12):

Should use EventingBasicConsumer. I have an example on my website that shows how it's used [RabbitMQ Events using EventingBasicConsumer](http://www.jarloo.com/listening-to-rabbitmq-events/)

Basically it's just a new consumer that exposes a Received event so you don't need to block.